# Is it possible to upload a windows image to Google compute engine?

Tags: windows, google-compute-engine

I'm wondering if there's a way to upload windows image to Google compute cloud?

I've seen Google's tutorials for Linux based OS but I couldn't find any reference to Windows except the fact the it is possible to install windows software, and that it's possible to create instances using their own images:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows and 
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/ms-licensing

In case that it's possible, I'd like to know what's the process of doing that using an Hyper-V image.

Thanks,
David.

Comment: Similar question has been answered on google groups thread (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/gce-discussion/custom$20windows$20image/gce-discussion/BCC50xcLHNo/GWKsjSt563wJ)

Comment: I don't know what's up with Faizan's link, but it should point to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gce-discussion/BCC50xcLHNo