# Possibility of migration Amazon EC2 Windows images to Google Compute Engine

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, google-compute-engine

Maybe anyone know the way how to migrate Windows images from Amazon EC2 to Google Compute Engine and back. I've read about the Linux images migration in GCE documentation, but there are no any info about the Windows images. I also seen this [Is it possible to upload a windows image to Google compute engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31426573/is-it-possible-to-upload-a-windows-image-to-google-compute-engine) question, but reference to google group is banned, so I can't read it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry there was a problem with that Groups link. The answer I wrote there was that at least two companies offer migration tools for moving a Windows VM into GCE. One is Racemi, and the other is CloudEndure.

Comment: This is not an answer as-is.

Comment: It is exactly the answer described on the Google Group that the questioner mentioned he couldn't access (I agree, something was wrong with given link). Perhaps you could provide more constructive feedback on how you think this answer should be different?

Comment: Because it references a link that isn't present. The answer seems lacking in context. If the sum total of the answer is that there are two companies, then that is an answer.

Comment: The link should look like https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gce-discussion/BCC50xcLHNo -- does that get mangled also?

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to update this to reflect that GCE now has an "Import VM" option on the Cloud Console.  This will direct you to a service that will enable free migration of Windows VMs

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll check this options.